# Enabling cache for exoplayer

Tags: android, caching, video, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have implemented exoplayer for hls video links, once video played it again loads the video to play, can anyone suggest how to stop loading again and play without buffering once video completely streamed.
How to store cache for hls streaming video.Please provide solutions if any.
Thanks in advance :)

```
 TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);

    DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(1024, 64 * 1024, 1024, 1024)
            .createDefaultLoadControl();


    videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector,loadControl);
```

//         player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);

```
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    videoView.setPlayer(player);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
    Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayer"));

// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();


    MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl));

    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Follow Video cache library instruction : https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache

Comment: @TusharLathiya currently i have changed from exoplayer to videoview to see if it works or not but again it is not working

Comment: Bro  please share your code. currently working perfect in my App. it is working for videoview and exoplayer to. if not working pls let me know.

Comment: @TusharLathiya can you share your exoplayer code

Comment: refer this: https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache/tree/exoPlayer

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:** Using Exoplayer cache strategy

step 1 : Implement Exoplayer

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.15.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.0'
```

step 2 : Create cache strategy in your Application class

```
public SimpleCache simpleCache;
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor leastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(100 * 1024 * 1024);
        if (simpleCache == null) {
            simpleCache = new SimpleCache(getCacheDir(), leastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor, new ExoDatabaseProvider(this));
        }
}
```

step 3 : Cache content like below method

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("YOUR URL");
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
        DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
        DefaultDataSource.Factory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(), httpDataSourceFactory);
        CacheDataSource.Factory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSource.Factory()
                .setCache(MyApplication.getAppInstance().simpleCache)
                .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(defaultDataSourceFactory)
                .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(mediaItem);
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource, true);
```

**Method 2:**
Android Video Cache Library do exact what you want. Follow below step to cache your videos.

step 1 : `implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.1'`

step 2 : store shared proxy in your Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private HttpProxyCacheServer proxy;
        public static HttpProxyCacheServer getProxy(Context context) {
            MyApplication app = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
            return app.proxy == null ? (app.proxy = app.newProxy()) : app.proxy;
        }
    
        private HttpProxyCacheServer newProxy() {
            return new HttpProxyCacheServer.Builder(this)
                    .maxCacheSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
                    .build();
            //return new HttpProxyCacheServer(this);
    
        }
}
```

step 3 : put MyApplication class in manifest file like

```
<application
        android:name=". MyApplication">
.
.
.
</application>
```

step 4 : use url from proxy instead of original url for adding caching

```
HttpProxyCacheServer proxy = MyApplication.getProxy(activity);
            String proxyUrl = proxy.getProxyUrl(VIDEO_URL);
            videoView.setVideoPath(proxyUrl);
```

if you are using exoplayer

```
HttpProxyCacheServer proxy = getProxy(activity);
                String proxyUrl = proxy.getProxyUrl(VIDEO_URL);
PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
      ExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(VideoActivity.this,
                new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                new DefaultTrackSelector());
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(proxyUrl);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will implement it and let you know if any issue will be there. Thanks again.

Comment: return app.proxy == null ? (app.proxy = app.newProxy()) : app.proxy; giving error. (Cannot resolve symbol 'proxy')

Comment: step 2:  store shared proxy in your Application class, what does this mean.

Comment: @AkashManjhi edited my answer in very easy way. if you want understand please do googling you will get all answer for your error.

Comment: I have implemented your code but video is not playing.

Comment: second one is good and simple for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This should be somewhere in singleton class

```
    val dbProvider = ExoDatabaseProvider(context)
    val cacheSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024 //100 mb
    simpleCache = SimpleCache(
        File(context.filesDir, "media"),
        LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(cacheSize), 
        dbProvider
    )
```

Write in your fragment or activity with player

```
val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("Exo Player"))
val cacheFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(simpleCache, defaultDataSourceFactory)
val mediaSource = DownloadHelper.createMediaSource(request, cacheFactory)
player.prepare(mediaSource)
```

P.S. You can calculate cache size differently. Google recommends to create it depending on device RAM

```
    // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
    // int in its constructor.
    val maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8
    val evictor  = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(cacheSize)
```